# Multiply by the factor the number of times that the position appears in the array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to get a "pythonic" way or using a library **(anything except "for" loops)** for doing this.

```
my_array = np.array([2,4,6])
my_array[[0,2,0]] = my_array[[0,2,0]] * 2
```

Expected result:

```
[8,4,12]
```

However, I get:

```
[4,4,12]
```

This doesn't work for me as I need to multiply twice the factor (2) for the position 0 if, through the index, the 0 position repeats n amount of times.

**"For" loops can't be used as there are billions of data points**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
>>> num_occurrences_list = [0,2,0]
>>> factor = 2
>>> my_array * np.power(factor, np.bincount(num_occurrences_list))
array([ 8,  4, 12])
```

But I am not sure if it provides any advantage over using for loops explicitly.

Here, `np.bincount` provides an array where each index contains the number of occurrences of it in your list. `np.power` with base 2 specifies how many times you want to multiply by 2. Finally, you perform the actual multiplication with the computed weights for each element of the array.

Comment: Thank you! It worked pretty well and improved my performance time! :D